# Decode the Morse code, advanced JS (codewars)

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, morse-code

Here is a task:

> When transmitting the Morse code, the international standard specifies
> that:
>
> "Dot" – is 1 time unit long. "Dash" – is 3 time units long. Pause
> between dots and dashes in a character – is 1 time unit long. Pause
> between characters inside a word – is 3 time units long. Pause between
> words – is 7 time units long. However, the standard does not specify
> how long that "time unit" is. And in fact different operators would
> transmit at different speed. An amateur person may need a few seconds
> to transmit a single character, a skilled professional can transmit 60
> words per minute, and robotic transmitters may go way faster.
>
> For this kata we assume the message receiving is performed
> automatically by the hardware that checks the line periodically, and
> if the line is connected (the key at the remote station is down), 1 is
> recorded, and if the line is not connected (remote key is up), 0 is
> recorded. After the message is fully received, it gets to you for
> decoding as a string containing only symbols 0 and 1.
>
> For example, the message HEY JUDE, that is ···· · −·−−   ·−−− ··− −··
> · may be received as follows:
>
> 1100110011001100000011000000111111001100111111001111110000000000000011001111110011111100111111000000110011001111110000001111110011001100000011
>
> As you may see, this transmission is perfectly accurate according to
> the standard, and the hardware sampled the line exactly two times per
> "dot".
>
> That said, your task is to implement two functions:
>
> Function decodeBits(bits), that should find out the transmission rate
> of the message, correctly decode the message to dots ., dashes - and
> spaces (one between characters, three between words) and return those
> as a string. Note that some extra 0's may naturally occur at the
> beginning and the end of a message, make sure to ignore them. Also if
> you have trouble discerning if the particular sequence of 1's is a dot
> or a dash, assume it's a dot.
> 2. Function decodeMorse(morseCode), that would take the output of the previous function and return a human-readable string.

Here is my code:

```js
var MORSE_CODE = {
    ".-":"A",
    "-...":"B",
    "-.-.":"C",
    "-..":"D",
    ".":"E",
    "..-.":"F",
    "--.":"G",
    "....":"H",
    "..":"I",
    ".---":"J",
    "-.-":"K",
    ".-..":"L",
    "--":"M",
    "-.":"N",
    "---":"O",
    ".--.":"P",
    "--.-":"Q",
    ".-.":"R",
    "...":"S",
    "-":"T",
    "..-":"U",
    "...-":"V",
    ".--":"W",
    "-..-":"X",
    "-.--":"Y",
    "--..":"Z",
};

var decodeBits = function(bits){

  const trimBits = bits.replace(/(^0+|0+$)/g, '').split('')
  const result = []
  var word = []
  if(trimBits.length > 3){
    trimBits.every((v, i, array) => {
      if(i > 0 && i < array.length - 1){
        return v == array[i-1] ? word.push(v) : result.push(word) && (word = []) && word.push(v)
      }else  if(i == array.length - 1){
        return v == array[i-1] ? word.push(v) && result.push(word) : result.push(word) && result.push([v])
      }else{
        return word.push(v)
      }
    })
    if(result.length === 1){
      return result[0][0] == 1 ? '.'.repeat(result[0].length / 3) : '-'.repeat(result[0].length / 3)
    }else if(result.map((v) => v.join(''))[1].length == 1 && result.length == 3){
      let result1 = result.map((v) => v.join(''))
      return result1.map((v) => v[0] == 1 ? '.' : '   ').join('')

    }else{
      return result.map((v) => v.join('')).map((v) => {
        if(v[0] == 0){
          if(v.length % 2 == 0){
            if(v.length > 6){
              return '       '
            }if(v.length == 6){
              return '   '
            }else{
              return ' '
            }
          }else if(v.length >= 6){
            return '       '
          }else if(v.length === 3){
            return '   '
          }else{
            return String.fromCharCode(32)
          }
        }else if(v[0] == 1){
          if(v.length % 2 == 0 && v.length % 3 != 0){
            return String.fromCharCode(46).repeat(v.length / 2)
          }else if(v.length % 3 == 0){
            return String.fromCharCode(45)
          }else{
            return String.fromCharCode(46)
          }
        }
      }).join('')
    }
  }else{
    
    return trimBits.every((v, i, arr) => v === arr[0]) && trimBits[0] == 1 ? '.' : '..'
  }
}

var decodeMorse = function(morseCode){
  return morseCode.split('       ').map((v) => v.split('   ')).map((v) => v.map((val) => MORSE_CODE[val.replace(/ /g, '')]).join('')).join(' ')
}

decodeMorse(decodeBits('1100110011001100000011000000111111001100111111001111110000000000000011001111110011111100111111000000110011001111110000001111110011001100000011'))// returns 'HEY JUDE'
decodeMorse(decodeBits('1110111')) //returns EE
console.log(decodeMorse(decodeBits('00011100010101010001000000011101110101110001010111000101000111010111010001110101110000000111010101000101110100011101110111000101110111000111010000000101011101000111011101110001110101011100000001011101110111000101011100011101110001011101110100010101000000011101110111000101010111000100010111010000000111000101010100010000000101110101000101110001110111010100011101011101110000000111010100011101110111000111011101000101110101110101110'))) //THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.
```

The problem is that every time I'm running my code I've got the same issues:

```
Expected: 'A', instead got: 'EE'
Expected: 'M', instead got: 'EE'
Expected: 'E', instead got: 'I'

Expected: 'THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.', instead got: 'T H E Q U I C K B R O W N F O X J U M P S O V E R T H E L A Z Y D O G .'
```

I've tried all of my best and I've stacked. Can anybody help me to find the solution here? What am I doing wrong at this code?

For debugging:

```js
decodeMorse(decodeBits('1100110011001100000011000000111111001100111111001111110000000000000011001111110011111100111111000000110011001111110000001111110011001100000011'))// returns 'HEY JUDE'
decodeMorse(decodeBits('1110111')) //returns EE
```

**Updated post! I'm very close. Something wrong with spaces and with single letter.**

P.S. The error might be in the decoder logic where I'm trying to resolve what should I push to the array `result` dash or dot.

Comment: Right now, the code doesn't do what you say because you haven't included a definition for `MORSE_CODE`...

Comment: I'll fix it now

Comment: It appears as though you're using `every` for side effects; you should be either doing something with the output (a Boolean indicating if every element of the array satisfies the condition), or use `forEach` for plain iteration with no meaningful return value. I'd also suggest not being quite so "clever" in the code within that function. It's not clear on first read what `return v == array[i - 1] ? word.push(v) : result.push(word) && (word = []) && word.push(v)` will do. I find that if I have a problem with code, the first thing I do is make sure I can read it aloud and make sense.

Comment: This chunk of code is doing good(just trust me :) ). The error is somewhere in logic of decoding it where I'm trying to go through the array `return result.map((v) => v.join('')).map((v)...` and somwhere i'm missing something.

Comment: I think what I'm missing is what the problem is. Can you edit the snippet to include an example of an input that's returning an incorrect output? For instance, what's giving you those Expected: '...', instead got: '...' errors?

Comment: if (result.map((v) <-- why are you using a map in an if?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are testing with this: decodeMorse(decodeBits('1110111')) //returns EE as the binary string isn't one you'd expect to receive.

Comment: Yep. For example: `decodeMorse(decodeBits('110111'))` should return `A` but it returns `EE`. I'm fixing it right now.

Comment: @Morani 1110111 should be M, speed = 1, line (pause) line, 111, 0, 111. There is no other possible speed because the single 0 can be generated only at speed = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this! My first the most interesting task in js. The reason of failure was wrong spaces in condition. I should prevent that spaces can be odd and even number of zeros. **Upvote it please**. Maybe it will help someone. I've spend almost 10 hours to resolve it xD

```js
var MORSE_CODE = {
        ".-":"A",
        "-...":"B",
        "-.-.":"C",
        "-..":"D",
        ".":"E",
        "..-.":"F",
        "--.":"G",
        "....":"H",
        "..":"I",
        ".---":"J",
        "-.-":"K",
        ".-..":"L",
        "--":"M",
        "-.":"N",
        "---":"O",
        ".--.":"P",
        "--.-":"Q",
        ".-.":"R",
        "...":"S",
        "-":"T",
        "..-":"U",
        "...-":"V",
        ".--":"W",
        "-..-":"X",
        "-.--":"Y",
        "--..":"Z",
    };

var decodeBits = function(bits){

  const trimBits = bits.replace(/(^0+|0+$)/g, '').split('')
  const result = []
  var word = []
  if(trimBits.length > 3){
    trimBits.every((v, i, array) => {
      if(i > 0 && i < array.length - 1){
        return v == array[i-1] ? word.push(v) : result.push(word) && (word = []) && word.push(v)
      }else  if(i == array.length - 1){
        return v == array[i-1] ? word.push(v) && result.push(word) : result.push(word) && result.push([v])
      }else{
        return word.push(v)
      }
    })
    if(result.length === 1){
      return result[0][0] == 1 ? '.' : '-'.repeat(result[0].length / 3)
    }else if(result.map((v) => v.join(''))[1].length == 1 && result.length == 3){
      let result1 = result.map((v) => v.join(''))
      return result1.map((v) => v[0] == 1 ? (v.length <= 2 ? '.' : '-') : (v.length >= 1 ? ' ' : '   ')).join('')

    }else{
      return result.map((v) => v.join('')).map((v) => {
        if(v[0] == 0){
          if(v.length % 2 == 0){
            if(v.length > 6){
              return '       '
            }if(v.length == 6){
              return '   '
            }else{
              return ' '
            }
          }else if(v.length == 7){
            return '       '
          }else if(v.length == 3){
            return '   '
          }else if(v.length > 7){
            return '   '.repeat(v.length / 7 - 1)
          }else{
            return ' '
          }
        }else if(v[0] == 1){
          if(v.length % 2 == 0 && v.length % 3 != 0){
            return String.fromCharCode(46).repeat(v.length / 2)
          }else if(v.length % 3 == 0){
            return String.fromCharCode(45)
          }else{
            return String.fromCharCode(46)
          }
        }
      }).join('')
    }
  }else{
    
    return trimBits.every((v, i, arr) => v === arr[0]) && trimBits[0] == 1 ? '.' : '..'
  }
}

var decodeMorse = function(morseCode){
  return morseCode.split('       ').map((v) => v.split('   ')).map((v) => v.map((val) => MORSE_CODE[val.replace(/\s/g, '')]).join('')).join(' ')
}

console.log(decodeMorse(decodeBits('1110110111')))
console.log(decodeMorse(decodeBits('00011100010101010001000000011101110101110001010111000101000111010111010001110101110000000111010101000101110100011101110111000101110111000111010000000101011101000111011101110001110101011100000001011101110111000101011100011101110001011101110100010101000000011101110111000101010111000100010111010000000111000101010100010000000101110101000101110001110111010100011101011101110000000111010100011101110111000111011101000101110101110101110')))
console.log(decodeMorse(decodeBits('11111100111111')))
console.log(decodeMorse(decodeBits('1100110011001100000011000000111111001100111111001111110000000000000011001111110011111100111111000000110011001111110000001111110011001100000011')))
```

Comment: Why is K 1110110111 instead of being 111010111?

Comment: `if(v.length % 2 == 0 && v.length % 3 != 0){
            return String.fromCharCode(46).repeat(v.length / 2)
          }else if(v.length % 3 == 0){
            return String.fromCharCode(45)
          }else{
            return String.fromCharCode(46)
          }` this code is checking for it. And you can read a task below.

Comment: I'm not asking why the code accepts it. I'm asking from a human point of view why K, that is -.-, so 111 0 1 0 111, is accepted as 1110110111, so with two ones for the dot.